# How can I remove my Google account from my friends phone?

Tags: google-account

I used my Google account to set up my friend's phone but she gets all my info. How do I stop my information from going to her phone?

Comment: Do you have access to your friends phone? If yes goto Settings->Accounts and select your account and click the three dot  and press remove to remove your account from that phone

Answer (score 2):

Few things that may work:
Go to Settings->Accounts, select your account, press menu key or three dots and remove your account
If you don't have access to your friend's phone, then you can remote wipe it, but you'll probably want your friend back, so you can also change password of your google account to prevent access of account on phone
You might also be able to remove devices here: https://security.google.com/settings/security/activity